# How to prevent git apply from staging its changes?

Tags: git

I have a patch file that I want to reverse from my source.

The patch is not 100% perfect, I used

```
git apply -3 -R patch.diff
```

to apply the reverse. But I am confused that after making changing, `git diff` is only showing me the conflicts. I instead want to see all the changes I applied remain as changes (i.e. `git diff` should show the patch but in reverse) and not staging to my local branch. What should I do?

Comment: Per the documentation, `git apply`  does not create any commits (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply#:~:text=but%20does%20not%20create%20a%20commit). Can you please elaborate your problem?

Comment: I think maybe the right word is "staging". I am only concerned about the output from `git diff`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have conflicts, the non-conflicts are staged and only the conflicts are left unstaged in your tree. `git diff HEAD` to show the *uncommitted* changes. `git diff` (without any argument) only shows *unstaged* changes. This is true for any conflicts, regardless of their cause: merge, rebase, cherry-pick, am, apply.

Changes can be staged with `git add path/to/file` and unstaged again with `git reset path/to/file`. [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) without a path unstages all currently-staged files. This information is also present in the output of `git status`.

Comment: You are right. Can you update your answer to say `git reset` will make the staged changes appear in diff again. I will accept the answer.